# Update a many-to-many relationship in Doctrine

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, doctrine, many-to-many

I have an article-category relationship and I'd like to update the relationship when necessary. That means, adding or removing the desired categories from an article. I use a php (ZF) setup with Doctrine 1.2. In YAML, the config looks (simplified) like this:

```
Article:
  columns:
    id: bigint(10)

Category:
  columns:
    id: bigint (10)
  relations:
    articles:
      foreignAlias: categories
      class: Article
      refClass: CategoryArticle

CategoryArticle:
  columns:
    category_id: bigint (10)
    article_id: bigint (10)
  relations:
    category:
      class: Category
      foreignAlias: categoryArticle
    article:
      class: Article
      foreignAlias: categoryArticle
```

I have a persisted $article where all old categories are available. With a POST request I get a list of category ids which should be the new ones. I have this so far:

```
$oldCategories = array();
foreach ($article->categories as $cat) {
    $oldCategories[] = $cat->id;
}
$newCategories = $form->getValue('categories');

$diffRemove = array_diff($oldCategories, $newCategories);
$diffAdd    = array_diff($newCategories, $oldCategories);
foreach ($diffRemove as $id) {
    // Remove all the categories $id from article [1]
}
foreach ($diffAdd as $id) {
    // Add all the categories $id to article [2]
}
```

My question is about [1] and [2]. What is the best performance to add and remove a many:many relationship?

Comment: Which version of doctrine are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Deletion

The most efficient way of deleting en masse in SQL is using single sql statement with some conditions set, something like

```
delete from Products where id>3
```

It make use of indexes, partitioning, etc.

There is a way to achieve that value of performance using Doctrine 1.2 - using DQL [DELETE](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en#delete-queries) statements. As shown in documentation, the following query transforms into the above SQL:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->delete('Products p')
    ->where('p.id > 3');
```

In your case, you could optimize deletion with something like

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->delete('CategoryArticle ca')
    ->where('ca.article_id=?', $article_id)
    ->andWhereIn('ca.category_id', $diffRemove);
```

This code should generate something like:

```
delete from CategoryArticle 
where article_id = $article_id and category_id in ($diffremove)
```

### Insertion

With insertion you could use `CategoryArticle` entity. The most effective way to do that with Doctrine is to build up a collection of Entities and than save that collecion:

```
$collection = new Doctrine_Collection('CategoryArticle');
foreach ($diffAdd as $id){
    $ca = new CategoryArticle();
    $ca->category = $id;
    $ca->article = $article_id;
    $collection[] = $ca;
}

$collection->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You provide a very good option for my question, I just stumbled upon the "collection insertion" myself. For deletion, I use now another slightly different foreach loop: `$q = $obj->getTable()->getQueryObject()->delete('CategoryArticle ca')`. Then inside the loop I add an orWhere() clause: `$q->orWhere('ca.article_id=? AND ca.category_id=?, array($articleId, $categoryId))`. So this makes nested where clauses and I'm able to delete all old articles in 1 query (!).

Comment: Well, with your approach you'll end up with deletion query that looks something like `delete from CategoryArticle where article_id = 1 or article_id = 2 or article_id = 3 or article_id = 4` .... I think that will not affect the performance, but that's a very loooooong query :) And, maybe I'm missing something, but your query might remove associations with other articles. Try outputting actual SQL with $q->getSqlQuery() and see, if category_id condition is present in it. If no - you are have a risk of removing associations that should be kept.

Comment: Ran out of words :). With `andWhereIn` the query is very short: just `delete from CategoryArticle where article_id in (1,2,3,4) and category_id = *category_id*`

Comment: Ah, I misread your query. `andWhereIn()` will do the trick indeed. My approach works as well, because it creates the query `delete from CategoryArticle where (article_id=1 AND category_id=2) OR (article_id=1 AND category_id=3)`. But still your query is more appropriate.

Comment: Ah, right, there are two conditions in single `orWhere`. I've read it as separate `orWhere` and `andWhere`. Don't know how, probably my eyes played a trick with me.